# About "this" in jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, jquery-events

In code like this:

```
    var test = function (e,name) {
        this.e = e;
        this.name = name;
        this.init();
    };
    test.prototype.init = function () {
        var $e = $(this.e);
        var _this = this;
        $e.click(function () {
            alert(_this.name);
            //show the current name
        });
        $('#AA').click(function () {
            alert(_this.name);
            //show all the name
        })
    };
    new test($("#A"),"A");
    new test($("#B"),"B");
```

why click `"$e"` only shows the current name,
whereas click `"$('#AA')"` shows all the name.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WinKiFlyMe/8HdRw/)

Comment: Looks like Jquery to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the click handler for `#AA` is attached twice.

```
new test($("#A"),"A");
new test($("#B"),"B");
```

You call the `test` constructor two times, once for `#A`, once for `#B`. `init` gets called two times, so

```
$('#AA').click(function () {
    alert(_this.name);
    //show all the name
})
```

will be run two times too.

In the advanced event handling model (`addEventListener`, jQuery uses that too of course) event handlers don't replace each other (like with the old `onclick` and friends), but they add up instead. So if you add the same event handler 5 times to an element, it will be run 5 times when the event triggers.

Answer (score 3):

That happens because you invoke:

```
    $('#AA').click(function () {
        alert(_this.name);
        //show all the name
    })
```

both for `#A` and `#B`.

When you call: `new test($("#A"),"A");` the method `init` is called which leads to attachment of the click callback, so when you click on `#AA` `A` will be alerted.

After that you call: `new test($("#B"),"B");`. This leads to call of `init` with different values. One more click handler is attached to `#AA` so when you click on the element you get two alerts.

Answer (score 0):

@kapa and @Minko are correct.

One quick soluction is to use `unbind()` to avoid the handler being added twice:

```
        $('#AA').unbind("click").click(function () {
            alert(_this.name);
            //show all the name
        })
```

[unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) will remove the click handler if it was previously added. So we are making sure that it is added once.

**EDIT**: In a serious application use `off()` instead of `unbind()`. See the docs for `off` [here](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

Comment: Be careful though, because calling `unbind()` removes **every** event handler from the element for all event types. This is not a good idea in most cases, as plugins or other parts of your code can attach event handlers to the same element, and this way they are destroyed. The right solution would be to use [event namespaces](http://css-tricks.com/namespaced-events-jquery/). Btw, since 1.7, `off()` is preferred instead of `unbind()`.

Comment: I have edited and configured it to remove just click handlers. You are right about `off()`.

Comment: I would still advise to use namespaces, as the problem still applies, even though now only for the `click` handlers. Mysterious, hard-to-track-down bugs can appear if you simply remove every `click` handler from an element.  Of course not in a 20-line jsFiddle, but in a project with several components that all attach their own handlers.

Comment: I agree. I have added the advice in my answer.

Comment: The important point was namespaces. `unbind()` supports namespaces, and basically `unbind()` is the same as `off()` (if you don't take event delegation into account). Whatever, in the comments one can find all the important details now :).

Comment: Great. Yes, all the details are here :)